# Java basic, reversing a word and how it is achieved through a for loop

Tags: java

I am new towards coding, so I've managed to create a code that allows me to reverse words, however, I don't fully understand the for loop construct, because I created this using online resources.

```
public class word {                                     
    public static String rWords(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split("");
        String output = " ";                

        for (int i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            output += (split[i] + "");
        }

        return output.trim();                                       
    }                                       
}
```

Say there is already a main class that contains a string value of input, this is another class called word, I understand that making it public static string means it's public and static means it's not declared in instances. It contains one parameter with the input from main class, the output is empty for my for loops results to go into that, however, how does the for loop allow my input to be reversed and return.trim do?

Comment: If you're genuinely just asking "how does code work" then this is an opportune time to start using your debugger.  With a debugger (available in any IDE) you can set breakpoints to pause the execution of the code on any given line and then begin to step through the live running code one line at a time, observing how each operation modifies the variables.  When you do this, do you encounter a specific line of code which does something you didn't expect?  What did it do?  What did you expect it to do?  Why?

Comment: You do know that strings are immutable once they are declared right? If you want to mutate strings use StringBuilder instead

Comment: Understanding the loop will be easier when you clarify the output of the String methods. For editing Strings use StringBuilder as Stephan Hogenboom said. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use out-of-box approach? E.g. `StringBuilder` already has a method `reverse()`:

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.trim().split("\\s+"))
                 .map(word -> new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString())
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

But you string can do it with old Java:

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    // using StringBuilder for multiple string concatenation
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (String word : str.trim().split("\\s+")) {
        // add space if word is not first one
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(' ');

        // add each word from end to beginning
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            buf.append(word.charAt(i));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

In case you need swap words in the sentence, principle is the same:

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    String[] words = str.trim().split("\\s+");

    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(' ');

        buf.append(words[i]);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: Using streams and lambdas might cause more confusion concerning that he has stated being a beginner. The aim of GeorgeJun seems to be to implement the method himself and understanding the process step by step. Optimization and the usage of other classes may be secondary at this point.

Comment: @CrimsonMike Yep, I think you're right. I have added more string method.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which was to explain how the code worked. Given how simple that is, creating more code doesn't really help.